# Swashbuckle failed to load api definition in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, swagger

In My solution I have a 'web' project and an 'API' project web being my front end app with MVC Controllers and my API which is my Restful service that also has controllers. At the moment to keep it simple I have 1 restful 'POST' function and a number of mainly get methods in my 'web' project.

In the web project I've made a reference to swashbuckle and then in startup.cs file I have the following code:

in the Configure Services after adding `services.AddMvc()` I have:

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
   {
     c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Swagger", Version = "v1" });
   });
```

then in the configure method before I set `app.UseMvc()` I have:

```
 app.UseSwagger();
 app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
 {
     c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "swagger for EV");

 });
```

I want to see all my methods from both projects, but at the moment I don't get any. I have made a point of placing either `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpPost]` on all methods